# I have a file. I need to print all the quantities with unique values no duplicates, using perl

Tags: command-line, text-processing, perl

In example below, quantity is the field with the '38' tag, e.g. 38=100 on the first line.

```
Order:167342,9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|1=30532|114=Y|40=1|35=D|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|11=|38=100|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|

Order:544291,52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|40=1|35=D|34=388|11=|38=100|56=MBT|1=30532|114=Y|10=085|55=/GCQ3|9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|

Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|34=388|11=|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|

Order:332907,9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|56=MBT|114=Y|1=30532|55=/GCQ3|10=085|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|35=D|40=1|38=26|11=|34=388|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|

Order:385327,38=100|34=388|11=|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|9=205|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|56=MBT|

Order:610550,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=521|11=|34=388|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|

Order:408689,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|38=658|34=388|11=|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|

Order:43899,56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|21=1|49=11342|553=2453|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|40=1|35=D|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|11=|34=388|38=531|
```

Output:-
if there are three 38tags with same values then only one output would be shown: Outcome should be like this:-

```
Order:167342,9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|56=MBT|10=08‌​5|55=/GCQ3|1=30532|1‌​14=Y|40=1|35=D|54=|6‌​0=20130624-09:45:02.‌​046|34=388|11=|38=10‌​0|52=20130624-09:45:‌​02.046|59=0|100=MBTX‌​|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4| 

Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|3‌​4=388|11=|59=0|52=20‌​130624-09:45:02.046|‌​8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|4‌​3=Y|9=205|553=2453|4‌​9=11342|21=1|56=MBT|‌​55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30‌​532|114=Y|
```

and so on .....

Comment: First of all, as Zanna properly noted, we need to know your desired output. Second, clarify  how exactly you want the lines with tag other than `38=100` be treated. Do they remain in the output ? What about  other fields of the line ? If line says `Order: 12345, 38=100` and another `Order: 5678 , 38=100` are these considered duplicate ? You question is very unclear right now, and we can't help you till you clarify

Comment: yes everything remains in the output.. if there are three 38tags with same values then only one output would be shown: Outcome should be like this:-Order:167342,9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|1=30532|114=Y|40=1|35=D|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|11=|38=100|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|                                                 Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|34=388|11=|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y| .... so on

Comment: but if there are two with `38=100` how to decide which one you actually want? It seems like information will be arbitrarily discarded (since you want the whole line)

Comment: if there are two with 38=100 then it will take one and the other would be considered as duplicate.. The solution you posted was correct

Comment: so you don't mind which one is discarded? you just want to keep a random one out of the 3 lines?

Comment: yes any one among them with same values

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged your question `perl`, how about using a perl hash?

```
$ perl -ne '/[,|](38=\d+)/ ; print unless $seen{ $1 }++' file
Order:167342,9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|1=30532|114=Y|40=1|35=D|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|11=|38=100|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|
Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|34=388|11=|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|
Order:332907,9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|56=MBT|114=Y|1=30532|55=/GCQ3|10=085|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|35=D|40=1|38=26|11=|34=388|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|
Order:610550,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=521|11=|34=388|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|
Order:408689,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|38=658|34=388|11=|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|
Order:43899,56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|21=1|49=11342|553=2453|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|40=1|35=D|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|11=|34=388|38=531|
```

---

To print the total number of lines at the end of processing, you can modify to

```
perl -ne '
  /[,|](38=\d+)/ ; print unless $seen{ $1 }++ ; 
  END { print "Total lines: $.\n" }
' file
```

or to print the total number of records (defined here as matches of the `38=\d+` quantity string)

```
perl -ne '
  $c += () = /[,|](38=\d+)/ ; print unless $seen{ $1 }++ ; 
  END { print "Total records: $c\n" }
' file
```

---

If you want the number of unique quantities, you can use the scalar value of the hash keys:

```
$ perl -ne '
  /[,|](38=\d+)/ ; print unless $seen{ $1 }++ ;
  END { print "Unique records: ", scalar keys %seen, "\n" }
' file
Order:167342,9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|1=30532|114=Y|40=1|35=D|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|11=|38=100|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|
Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|34=388|11=|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|
Order:332907,9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|56=MBT|114=Y|1=30532|55=/GCQ3|10=085|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|35=D|40=1|38=26|11=|34=388|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|
Order:610550,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=521|11=|34=388|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|
Order:408689,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|38=658|34=388|11=|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|
Order:43899,56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|21=1|49=11342|553=2453|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|40=1|35=D|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|11=|34=388|38=531|
Unique records: 6
```

If you want only the `38=qty` field, then simply print `$1` from the regex match:

```
$ perl -lne '
  /[,|](38=\d+)/ ; print $1 unless $seen{ $1 }++ ;
  END { print "Unique records: ", scalar keys %seen }
' file
38=100
38=234
38=26
38=521
38=658
38=531
Unique records: 6
```

---

To output the counts, you must wait until the `END` and then loop over the hash. You can optionally `sort` on the `keys` at that pont:

```
$ perl -lne '
  $seen{ $1 }++ if /[,|](38=\d+)/ ;
  END {
    for $key (sort keys %seen) { print "$seen{$key} $key" };
    print "Unique records: ", scalar keys %seen
  }
' file
3 38=100
1 38=234
1 38=26
1 38=521
1 38=531
1 38=658
Unique records: 6
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!!!! one last question ..also wanted to show total records it searched or total output lines?

Comment: @SonalAsija please see updated answer

Comment: @SonalAsija I have updated the answer again - you can use the scalar value of the hash's `keys` value

Comment: I really appreciate your help.. one last thing now how can i  just print the 38 tag not the complete sentence like 38=100,38=658,38=521...

Comment: @SonalAsija answer edited once more

Comment: thx.. if we need to show how many times a particular value is repeated than how we can achieve it.. like:- 12 38=100, 20 38=531, 55 38=521... here 12 represents 38=100 is repeated 12 times .. 38=531is repeated 20 times etc

Comment: @SonalAsija please see above - hopefully this is the FINAL edit

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question, this awk command should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -F "[,\|]" '
(NF>0){delete key
printf "%s,", $1
for (i=2; i<=NF-1; i++) {if (key[$i]!=1) printf "%s|", $i
            key[$i]=1}
printf "\n"}' <tf
```

(where the input is stored in the file tf)

Based on your input file, I get the output:

```
Order:167342,9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|1=30532|114=Y|40=1|35=D|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|11=|38=100|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|
Order:544291,52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|40=1|35=D|34=388|11=|38=100|56=MBT|1=30532|114=Y|10=085|55=/GCQ3|9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|
Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|34=388|11=|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|
Order:332907,9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|56=MBT|114=Y|1=30532|55=/GCQ3|10=085|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|35=D|40=1|38=26|11=|34=388|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|
Order:385327,38=100|34=388|11=|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|9=205|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|56=MBT|
Order:610550,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=521|11=|34=388|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|
Order:408689,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|38=658|34=388|11=|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|
Order:43899,56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|21=1|49=11342|553=2453|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|40=1|35=D|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|11=|34=388|38=531|
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but i need to run in perl

Comment: @SonalAsija why didn't you clearly say that in your question?!

Comment: output should be 6 lines if *I* understood correctly, which I am in doubt about

Comment: yes Zanna it should be of 6 lines

Comment: Zanna grep -oE '38=[^|]+' file | sort | uniq.. this works fine but instead of matching words i need the complete sentence

Comment: Sorry -- I am not familiar with perl